# Jconsole randomly stops connecting

Tags: jboss7.x, jmx, java-6, jconsole, spring-remoting

We have a jboss 7 instance running and hosting a web application. JMX remote has been turned on with username/password authentication and we are able to connect to it fine. Kindly not we are using Jboss/bin/jconsole.bat to connect.
However at times we notice after the following 2 cases it stops allowing any more connections to jmx unless we restart the jboss server. the cases are
1) we attempt a heap dump of the JVM using jconsole
2) We invoke a softreset method on a c3p0 datasource object that has been exposed via spring JMX

Not necessarily after doing any of the 2 it will always stop working. At times it stops taking new connections after trying one heap dump or at times after 3-4 successful attempts.
Any clue on this random behaviour of jconsole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ware bit by connection leak bug that AS 7.1.x had and it is fixed with 7.2.x versions.

I would recommend you to take EAP 6.1.0.Alpha1 (same as 7.2.0.Final) and try again.

If I recall correctly this was the original issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/REMJMX-45

Comment: Thanks - quite possible. It does happen when we are using jboss version of jconsole so may be related. We don't have jboss crashing but Jconsole stops working